# How to add this heading to list of equations

Tags: equations, lists, titletoc

I generated a list of equations in a report class with this code in preamble:

```
\DeclareCaptionType{myeqcap}[][List of Equations]
\captionsetup[myeqcap]{labelformat=empty}
```

Now, I want to add this heading to this list
[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example that shows what packages you use. There are different approaches to this, I guess.

Comment: The solution is to add the text as an entry in the list using \addtocontents.  You will need to know the extension for the file .

Comment: John Kormylo; Thanks, the file was lomyeqcap, and it works great.